# Is this how median-of-three quicksort works?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, quicksort

I know this question has been asked before. I've read them but i'm still not confident if what i've intepreted is right.

Lets say we have an array of `[51,20,26,16,19,38,10,37,49]`.

Firstly, we have to choose the median as pivot (first ,last and middle).

```
[51,19,49]
```

From that, 49 is the pivot and we move it the back.

Next, partition sub array `[51,20,26,16,19,38,10,37]` 49.

since 51 is the **first** element larger than 49 and 37 is the **first** element smaller than 49, we swap them.

```
[37,20,26,16,19,38,10,51]
  ^                    ^
```

Repeat the same step.

Since 51 is the first element that is larger than 49 but its index is bigger than 37, we swap pivot with 51. Now our array looks like:

```
[37,20,26,16,19,38,10,49,51]
```

Now 49 and 51 are sorted.

Then, we pick pivot again:[37,16,10] from `[37,20,26,16,19,38,10]`.

Swap pivot to back:
    [37,20,26,10,19,38,16]
Look for element larger than 16: `37`

Look for element smaller than 16 : `10`

Swap

```
[10,20,26,37,19,38,16]
```

Look for element larger than 16 : `20`

Look for element smaller than 16 : `10`

Since index of 20 > index of 10, i would swap pivot with 20

```
[10,16,26,37,19,38,20]
```

From here, i would repeat the steps from finding median to partitioning. However, i am really unsure if this is the right way. Sorry if this is a lengthy post, i tried to be as specific as possible about my thought process. Can someone tell me if what i'm doing is right?

Comment: "since 51 is the first element larger than 49 and 37 is the first element smaller than 49, we swap them." -- You don't know whether that's the case, you only know that one is larger and the other smaller than the pivot. Also, what you then do is that you put them in two separate arrays so that the pivot serves as element in the middle. It's an optimization detail that these two sequences are stored in one array. BTW: It's not clear from your description, but you don't switch pivots while in the middle of partitioning.

Comment: Does this mean that after my first partitioning ending with, `[37,20,26,16,19,38,10,49,51]`, i should choose the median again from [37,19,51]. Thus, my new median is 37 and i work from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are variations in median of three and the partition scheme, Lomuto or Hoare. For Hoare partition scheme, the median of three typically sorts first, middle, last:

```
[51,20,26,16,19,38,10,37,49] => [19,20,26,16,49,38,10,37,51]
```

Hoare scans from left and right. There are no values on the left >= 49, so the left scan stops when it reaches 49. The right scan stops at 37, since that is the first value <= 49, so the first swap results in

```
[19,20,26,16,37,38,10,49,51]
```

The left scan continues until it reaches 49 again. The right scan stops at 10. Since the right index is now <= left index, it stops the scan, and the uses recursion for

```
[19,20,26,16,37,38,10]   [49,51]
```

Note that Hoare only guarantees the left part elements are <= pivot, and the right part elements are >= pivot. Elements == pivot and the pivot itself may end up anywhere in the left and/or right parts.

---

Lomuto scheme typically only scans from the left, usually with the pivot on the right. Median of 3 could still swap similar to what I show above, except that it would result in first <= last <= middle. This would result in

```
[51,20,26,16,19,38,10,37,49] => [19,20,26,16,51,38,10,37] [49]
```

Lomuto then scans from the left, using two indexes, one that is updated every time, the other index is updated for each element < pivot, swapping as it goes along. This results in:

```
[19,20,26,16,38,10,37,51] [49]
```

Then the pivot is swapped with the first element >= pivot, which results in:

```
[20,26,16,19,38,10,37] [49] [51]
```

---

For Lomuto scheme, the median of 3 could be determined without swapping, then the median of 3 swapped to the last position, which would be the same as the question.

```
[51,20,26,16,19,38,10,37,49] => [51,20,26,16,19,38,10,37] [49]
```

The first partition step would result in:

```
[51,20,26,16,19,38,10,37] [49] => [20,26,16,19,38,10,37] [49] [51]
```

Comment: Thank you for your explaination!! However, does this mean what i'm doing wrong is that i am not sorting the 3 elements ( first, middle , last) in ascending order? Once i found the median `[49]`, I just swapped it to the back like this : `[51,20,26,16,19,38,10,37,49]`.

Comment: @Kirbbbb - I lost an edit. I updated my answer to show a third alternative of just swapping the median of 3 with last, which matches what you did in your question. There's no right or wrong. Median of 3 does eliminate worst case time complexity if the data is already sorted or reverse sorted. Hoare partition scheme is faster in typical cases, especially if there are duplicate values, which cause Lomuto to take more time and Hoare to take less time.

Comment: @Kirbbbb - I forgot to mention, Hoare scheme needs pivot to be in the middle, or at least not at first or last element, since it counts on elements == pivot to stop the scans from left and right. Lomuto scheme needs pivot to be last or first.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation. It looks much clearer to me now. Before i was reading around but was confused as to why they were so many different "versions" around. But now i know what i did was the Lomuto median of 3 scheme.